# Poor NN Accuracy (<20%)

Tags: neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to start getting my head around CNNs and started with a fairly simple data set of 213 rows. Each is classified so that it has to fit 6 from 98 categories. Even a simple 3 layer net is not exceeding 20% accuracy after 50k+ Epochs. Any suggestions?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Reshape
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy

ins = numpy.loadtxt("inputs.csv", delimiter=",")
outs = numpy.loadtxt("probs.csv", delimiter=",")

X = ins[:,0:9]
Y = outs[:,0:98]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=9, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(97, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error', optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50000, batch_size=200)
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Cheers,

L3fos

Comment: Please use only tags that are related to the question

Comment: Just on a side note: Your model is a feed forward neural network (ANN / DNN) rather than a CNN (= convolutional neural network).

Comment: Just another side note. If you have 98 classes and 213 rows data. So you have 2 samples per class, this is way to much. 
I don't know if you are new or a bad ass expert but the code looks very strange to me. If you are new, check out some code in github with a similar problem you want to solve. This helps much:)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right you use a dataset with 6 features and 98 classes.
98 classes are really much.

if we calculate 98 / 6 = 16.3 we get the value how good you can predict if you use random. You have 20 %
So you are a little bit better than random.

Is it possible that the data is to messy and is not related to the classes.

If you could show me you data and your goal, I could take a look:)

Comment: Is there a good way to attach csv files to the thread to share the data sets?

Comment: Yes of cause it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to set the activation of your first layer to ReLu.